# Issues Adding New Users to AWS QuickSight Enterprise Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-quicksight

I'm facing a challenging issue with my AWS managed QuickSight (Enterprise Edition) and could use some expert advice.

#### Issue Summary:

- **User Addition Problem**: I'm unable to add new users directly through QuickSight's "Manage Users" section. Previously, I would add users to a specific AWS group (let's call it QuickSight_Production group), and they would automatically appear in QuickSight. This method is no longer functioning.
- **Access Problems for New Users**: Newly added users cannot see the QuickSight app in their AWS startup apps. They only find a QuickSight_Production management console without access to QuickSight.
- **Endless Loading Issue**: When new users try to access, they face an indefinite loading screen with the URL "eu-west-1.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/sn/console/get-user-email".

#### Troubleshooting Done So Far:

- Checked IAM and SSO configurations.
- Verified the inline policy and trust relationships for the QuickSight-SSO role.
- Existing users, including myself, can access QuickSight without issues.

#### Additional Details:

- Unable to assign 'reader' roles - only 'admin' and 'author' are available.

I'm puzzled about why I can't add new users anymore, why they can't see the app, and why there's an indefinite loading for them. I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving these issues.

Thank you in advance for your help!